# how to extract multi level dictionary keys/values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

There is a two level dictionary in python:

for instance here: `index[term][id] = n`
how to get the  `term` and `n` when `id = 3`?

Or it would be perfect if it returns in a form like `result[id] = [term, n]`

Comment: are ids unique? can you provide what the actual dictionary looks like?

Comment: yes the id is unique, and the index actually store the words(term) from a collection of documents. index['and'][456]=7 means that in documnet456, 'and' occurs 7 times.

Comment: you could reverse your dictionary to be `index[documentId][word]=count`

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the nested dict and create new dict to map the values in the desired format. You can create your custom function like:

```
def get_tuple_from_value(my_dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for term, nested_dict in my_dict.items():
        for id, n in nested_dict.items():
            new_dict[id] = [term, n]
    return new_dict
```

OR, simple *dict comprehension* will look like:

```
{i: [t, n] for t, nd in d.items() for i, n in nd.items()}
```

where `d` is holding your dictionary.