# Aggregate Python lists stored as values in a nested dictionary into one list for arbitrary levels

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Suppose I have a nested dictionary where, at some level, the terminal values are lists. For example:

```
nested_dict = {1 : {'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [4,5]}, 
               2 : {'a' : [6],     'b' : [7,8,9]}}
```

I want to aggregate the list values into `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. For two levels I have

```
values = []
for key1 in nested_dict.keys():
    for key2 in nested_dict[key1].keys():
        for value in nested_dict[key1][key2]:
            values.append(value)
```

How can this be made more compact, and such that it handles arbitrary levels? That is, I know all the lists to be at the same level, but I don't know how deep, so in the code I provide I would effectively need an indeterminate number of for loops.

**Not a duplicate** of [how to extract multi level dictionary keys/values in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40657403/how-to-extract-multi-level-dictionary-keys-values-in-python) because they only show up to two levels.

Comment: @heather not a duplicate of that, they only handle 2 levels.

Comment: @SergeBallesta sorry, I fixed the syntax error.

Comment: I have posted a single line recursive function in the proposed [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427437/3545273).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
nested_dict = {1 : {'a' :[1,2,3], 'b': [4,5]}, 2 : {'a' : [6], 'b' : [7,8,9]}}
def get_lists(d):
   r = [b if isinstance(b, list) else get_lists(b) for b in d.values()]
   return [i for b in r for i in b]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I think this would be much nicer as a generator.  If the value `v` is a list, `yield from v` else `yield from get_lists(v)`